# How to change object value within an array of objects with one from another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Considering the two arrays bellow:

```
let aaa = [{label: "nu", angle: 5}, {label: "na", angle: 3}]
let bbb= [{label: "nu", angle: 2}, {label: "na", angle: 6}]
```

How can I add the value on the [angle](/questions/tagged/angle) key from one object with the corresponding one from the next array of objects and return one object or the other.

the result should be:

```
let ccc= [{label: "nu", angle: 7}, {label: "na", angle: 9}]
```

I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: Do items with same `label` have the same index in both arrays? Or can they be in random positions? Can `label` repeat in array?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the items will have the same index in both arrays.
The [tag: label] will not repeat.. it has to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) like this:

```js
let aaa = [{label: "nu", angle: 5}, {label: "na", angle: 3}];
let bbb= [{label: "nu", angle: 2}, {label: "na", angle: 6}];

const ccc = [...aaa, ...bbb].reduce((acc, a) => {
  const i = acc.findIndex(o => o.label === a.label);

  if(i === -1) { acc.push(a); return acc; }
  
  acc[i].angle += a.angle;
  return acc;      
 }, []);
 
 console.log(ccc);
```